# Auto sorting rows based on the values in a specific column?

Tags: sorting, google-sheets

Here's a sample table. It only has one formula which computes the total.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WW0uvAx3JfXkAt8qW89H4fHUTDmaY-zsjkhtaXQaJIM/edit?usp=sharing

I'm looking for a way that the table will automatically sort itself based on **TOTAL** column, after I input a new item in the list.

I know this can be done manually but automating it can really help me save some time.

Comment: what do u mean? like another spreadsheet? Sure I'll take any help I can get.

Answer (score 1):

In which case please try:

```
=query(Sheet1!A:D,"Select * order by D desc ")
```